# Почему подсвечивает красным?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Почему-то MealRepository repository подчёркнут красным жалуется на то что нет имплементации, а если её добавить то нечего не меняется

```
@Autowired
public MealServiceImpl(MealRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

Вот код:

```
@Service
public class MealServiceImpl implements MealService {

    private final MealRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MealServiceImpl(MealRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Meal get(int id, int userId) {
        return checkNotFoundWithId(repository.get(id, userId), id);
    }


    @Override
    public void delete(int id, int userId) {
        checkNotFoundWithId(repository.delete(id, userId), id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Meal> getBetweenDateTimes(LocalDateTime startDateTime, LocalDateTime endDateTime, int userId) {
        Assert.notNull(startDateTime, "startDateTime must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(endDateTime, "endDateTime  must not be null");
        return repository.getBetween(startDateTime, endDateTime, userId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Meal> getAll(int userId) {
        return repository.getAll(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Meal meal, int userId) {
        checkNotFoundWithId(repository.save(meal, userId), meal.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public Meal create(Meal meal, int userId) {
        Assert.notNull(meal, "meal must not be null");
        return repository.save(meal, userId);
    }
}
```

---

Вот MealRepository

```
import ru.javawebinar.topjava.model.Meal;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

public interface MealRepository {
// null if updated meal do not belong to userId
Meal save(Meal meal, int userId);

// false if meal do not belong to userId
boolean delete(int id, int userId);

// null if meal do not belong to userId
Meal get(int id, int userId);

// ORDERED dateTime desc
List<Meal> getAll(int userId);

// ORDERED dateTime desc
List<Meal> getBetween(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate, int userId);
```

}

Comment: А сам репозиторий то где?

Comment: такое бывает, если у MealRepository есть аннотация @NoRepositoryBean

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вы забыли пометить MealRepository аннотацией @Repository, если у вас включено сканирование пакетов. Если его нет, то бин MealRepository следует добавить в конфигурацию:

```
@Repository
public class MealRepository implements JPARepository...
```

или

```
@Bean
public MealRepository mealRepository() {
    return new MealRepository()
}
```

Comment: Попробовал добавить не помогло,

Comment: Если это Jpa репозитории он должен наследоваться от JpaRepository public interface MealRepository extends JpaRepository<Meal, Long>

Comment: Если нет, то должна быть реализация этого интерфейса, которую мы сможем зарегистрировать как бин в конфигурации

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart